# Write in docx file with PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, docx

I'm actually writing a PL/SQL package for Oracle Database auditing purpose (with informations like total RAM, OS version, memory ratio, ...) and I want to write the output of this audit in a docx file (or any file format readable and editable with Microsoft Office 2007).
How can I do that ?

I found a way, but it's not exactly what I want because you must use a template with tags and bind value one by one to these tag (http://ora-00001.blogspot.fr/2011/02/working-with-office-2007-ooxml-files.html). More, I must deploy a package before the audit and it's not always possible.

If I can do that without external package (third party), that would be cool !

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible to do without using an external library. I can only give you an outline though, not the actual code to do it.

Firstly, the `.docx`, `.xlsx` formats aren't actual documents; they're zip files. It's possible to [create a zip file](http://hidowb.blogspot.co.uk/2008/05/so-you-want-to-create-zip-file-in.html) from the database using a Java stored procedure. Secondly, the files therein are readable text formats, XML, etc.

If we look at one I created you can see what I mean.

```
[19:28:27]\\ELZAR\h:\ unzip -l blah.docx
Archive:  blah.docx
 Length    Date    Time    Name
 ------    ----    ----    ----
   2387  01-01-80  00:00   [Content_Types].xml
    590  01-01-80  00:00   _rels/.rels
   1880  01-01-80  00:00   word/_rels/document.xml.rels
 107400  01-01-80  00:00   word/document.xml
   2460  01-01-80  00:00   word/footer2.xml
   1428  01-01-80  00:00   word/endnotes.xml
   1434  01-01-80  00:00   word/footnotes.xml
   2624  01-01-80  00:00   word/header1.xml
    289  01-01-80  00:00   word/_rels/header1.xml.rels
   2497  01-01-80  00:00   word/footer1.xml
2765888  01-01-80  00:00   word/media/image1.emf
   7076  01-01-80  00:00   word/theme/theme1.xml
   4600  01-01-80  00:00   word/settings.xml
    363  01-01-80  00:00   word/_rels/settings.xml.rels
  25836  01-01-80  00:00   word/styles.xml
    341  01-01-80  00:00   customXml/itemProps1.xml
  54486  01-01-80  00:00   word/numbering.xml
    296  01-01-80  00:00   customXml/_rels/item1.xml.rels
    218  01-01-80  00:00   customXml/item1.xml
    808  01-01-80  00:00   docProps/core.xml
   2786  01-01-80  00:00   word/fontTable.xml
   2826  01-01-80  00:00   word/webSettings.xml
  26589  01-01-80  00:00   word/stylesWithEffects.xml
   1025  01-01-80  00:00   docProps/app.xml
 ------                    -------
3016127                    24 files
```

As these are all ordinary files you can write them all using something like [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm).

I would seriously consider your motivations for outputting to a `.docx`; it will not be easy, but yes; it's possible.

Why not simply store the information in the database and create a report based on that, which you could, for instance e-mail to yourself. Your life would be a lot easier.

Comment: What you say is very interesting but, I can't apply style to text apparently (or it's very difficult to write into many XML files at the same time to do that).
I know writing in .docx is not the best way and the more easy, but I don't have the choice. The tools will be use by other people in the company, and they want a document that can be open and edit with Word 2007.

Comment: If you're going to do this I would work at it from the other direction @Toin3. a) What formats can Word 2007 read and render in the way you want? Find the easiest to create and do that. b) If you decide to do .docx then create one, take it apart and study it. Work out how to create each file individually and gradually build it up to what you want. Writing many XML files can all be done in the same procedure so it'll take a while to create but it can definitely be done.

Comment: Yes, you're right.
With your approach, I think I find a way to obtain a .docx at the end.
I will try to write a HTML file with the PL/SQL procedure, and alter the mimetype to the docx mimetype. Word 2007 will open it without problem, and once the file is edited and saved from word, it will be convert with the real docx structure (I try and it's seems it works without error).
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Toin3 I did try it. altering mimetype as DOCX didn't work. MS Office raise an error saying that the content is corrupt. however, turning it into DOC worked fine.